# Using QtCreator 2.7.0 with OpenCV 2.4.5

Tags: qt, opencv, qt-creator

Until now I was working with OpenCV in VS 2012. Everything worked. Now I'm trying to work in QtCreator but I have a problem. When I run the project in debug I get the error:

```
"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\DetectorPietoni\mainwindow.cpp:4: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp': No such file or directory"
```

In release mode I get the error:

```
"mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)".
```

The code I am running is the next:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:\\PedestrianDetectionDataset\\test\\pos\\1.png");
}
```

And my setting are:

```
TARGET = DetectorPietoni
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += C:\OpenCV-2.4.5\\opencv\build\include

CONFIG(release,debug|release)
{
    LIBS += C:\\OpenCV-2.4.5\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc11\\lib\\opencv_core245.lib \
            C:\\OpenCV-2.4.5\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc11\\lib\\opencv_features2d245.lib \
            C:\\OpenCV-2.4.5\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc11\\lib\\opencv_highgui245.lib \
            C:\\OpenCV-2.4.5\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc11\\lib\\opencv_imgproc245.lib \
            C:\\OpenCV-2.4.5\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc11\\lib\\opencv_ml245.lib
}

CONFIG(debug,debug|release)
{
    LIBS += C:\\OpenCV-2.4.5\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc11\\lib\\opencv_core245d.lib \
            C:\\OpenCV-2.4.5\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc11\\lib\\opencv_features2d245d.lib \
            C:\\OpenCV-2.4.5\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc11\\lib\\opencv_highgui245d.lib \
            C:\\OpenCV-2.4.5\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc11\\lib\\opencv_imgproc245d.lib \
            C:\\OpenCV-2.4.5\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc11\\lib\\opencv_ml245d.lib
}
```

Any ideeas?

Comment: Your includepath has a couple of single backslashes, try replacing \ by \\, or use slashes instead. Not sure if that fixes it, though.

Comment: do you need to run qmake before RUN?

Comment: Yes if you've double checked the paths, do clean, qmake, build, run

Comment: if it can't find the include, the include path is wrong. If it can't link, you have not added the correct library (also check differences in platform/configuration). Doesn't the build create a logfile/outputs containing actual compiler/linker output so you can at least verify if they get invoked correctly by QtCreator as per your settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try coping `opencv.hpp` from `C:\OpenCV-2.4.5\opencv\build\include\opencv2` to `C:\OpenCV-2.4.5\opencv\build\include`

Then it might be able to locate the include.